# Nontraditional career/grad school path

Tags: reference-request

I'm a math major (got my BA in May 2014) currently working in finance. I really don't feel any motivation for my current job except that it pays the bills. I would like to know if anyone has made a jump from a non-chem background into something related to chemistry, be it a lab position, grad school etc.

My rationale for choosing chemistry is that I've enjoyed working in a lab for two summers and that physical sciences are very interesting for me.

Right now, my only option seems to be UCLA extension evening/weekend classes, maybe getting a part time lab gig at a local CC (or UCLA if I am very very lucky) and see if that will get me a job or a grad school.

Here are my questions:

1. How would I transition from having no chemistry background?
2. Do I have good reasons to switch to chemistry? What else should I ask myself before I make this change?

Thank you.

Best regards,
squelchy451

Comment: It's rather for Academia SE...

Comment: Concur -- these sorts of career track questions are [off-topic](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for this particular Stack Exchange site, per the [site definitions](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Great question for [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/), though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate on academia.SE.